# How to use Trim in select queries for data in SQL tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a table which stores data for AD users in one of columns like abc\sam, abc\bill, xyz\Ramos etc.. (domain\username)

I am trying to use select query to trim anything after\ and just give me domain with their location. That is, after trimming abc for example returns as NorthEast, xyz returns SouthPacfic etc.

Please suggest how can I write a SQL query for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your data

```
create  table test (c1 varchar(max));
insert into test values
('abc\sam'), 
('abc\bill'), 
('xyz\Ramos' );
```

you can use following queries to get your desired result
using `CHARINDEX` and `LEFT` and `RIGHT` functions

```
select 
LEFT(c1, CHARINDEX('\', c1) - 1) location 
--,RIGHT(c1, CHARINDEX('\', c1) - 1) username
FROM Test
```

using `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING`  functions

```
select 
SUBSTRING (c1,0,CHARINDEX('\',c1)) location
--,SUBSTRING(c1,CHARINDEX('\',c1)+1,LEN(c1)) username
FROM Test
```

Using `PARSENAME` function.however this method can not work with more than three `\`
like (`abc\sam\eee\fff`)

```
Select 
PARSENAME(replace(c1,'\','.'),2) location 
--,parsename(replace(c1,'\','.'),1) username
FROM Test
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9659466797be8e9745cb906ea85af909)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUBSTRING` to build your substring and `CHARINDEX` to find the 
backslash's position:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column, CHARINDEX('\', column) + 1, LEN(column)) FROM yourtable;
```